# How to access wacore container which is exiting due to file error present within - "/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I am launching containers via docker-compose, but 2 out of 3 containers are failing stating -:`"exec user process caused "exec format error" "`

The above error is caused while executing a file places at location `/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh`, i need to add `#!/bin/bash` at top of this file.
Problem is, the container is exiting in no time so how to access this file to make necessary changes ??

Below is the docker-compose.yml i am using -:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  whatsappMedia:
    driver: local
  postgresData:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.6
    command: "-p 3306 -N 500"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpass
      POSTGRES_USER: root
    expose:
        - "33060"
    ports:
        - "33060:3306"
    volumes:
     - postgresData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    network_mode: bridge
  wacore:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.31.4 docker-compose <command> <options>)}
    command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
    volumes:
     - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
      WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
      ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    network_mode: bridge
    links:
      - db
  waweb:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.31.4 docker-compose <command> <options>)}
    command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
    ports:
     - "9090:443"
    volumes:
     - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      WACORE_HOSTNAME: wacore
      # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
      WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
      ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "wacore"
    links:
      - db
      - wacore
    network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: Without seeing the image's Dockerfile or other details of how it was built, it's a little hard to diagnose this further.  (Does the image actually have GNU bash?  Does the script unintentionally have DOS line endings?)

Comment: (It's not relevant to your question, but you don't need to specify `network_mode:`, `links:`, or `expose:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file; those options don't do anything, particularly in modern Docker.)

Comment: Actually, this docker-compose file is built for Whattsapp api and hence i have copied this from official documentation of whatsap Business Api.. so haven't done much to modify it.  Rest i need to check contents inside file "/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh" problem is how to access this file as the container fails, is this file located somewhere on host OS ?

Comment: The file is present within the command ```command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_postgres.sh"``` the path seems to create within the container and when it executes this file throws an error due to which container exists, how to access the file to fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

Problem got resolved by using 64bit guest OS image.
I was running this container over 32 bit Centos which was causing the error.